# How To Auto Select Drop Down In magento..If drop downs have only one option

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I want To auto select All Drop Downs On Product Page. Which Have Only One Option.
I used Some  solution But Its Based On Removing Choose An Option.
By [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005824/disable-choose-an-option-in-configurable-products-of-magento) We Can Remove Choose An Option...

But My Need Is Not Removed Choose an Option....
How Can I do this.

Comment: please mention the version.

Comment: @AshishMadankar 1.9

Comment: Try after removing `dropdown[0].remove();` line

Comment: @AnilSuthar not working dropdown[0].remove();

Comment: start with index=1, like `for(index = 1; ` after removing that line

Comment: @AnilSuthar check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here You Can Make Attribute Selected...If DorpDown Have Only One Attribute....
Bellow of This code

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $_jsonConfig ?>);
```

Put this code....here..

```
 //we create new function
    spConfig.setInitialState = function (dropdown_id)
    {
        //select dropdown
        var dropdown = $(dropdown_id);
        //remove empty option from dropdown so it is not selectable after initial selection
        // dropdown[0].remove();
        //alert(dropdown.length);
        if (dropdown.length == 2) {
            dropdown[0].remove();// for the removing choose an option
           }
        //change selections in dropdowns
        for (index = 0; index < dropdown.length; index++)
        {
            if (dropdown[index].value != "")
            {
                dropdown.selectedIndex = index;
                var element = dropdown;
                var event = 'change';
                //fire events
                if (document.createEventObject)
                {
                    var evt = document.createEventObject();
                    return element.fireEvent('on' + event, evt)
                } else
                {
                    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                    evt.initEvent(event, true, true);
                    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }
            }
        }
    };
<?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        spConfig.setInitialState("attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>")
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: i used this code but no changes ,It still shows the default functionality

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but for those people still looking, here's how I solved it in jQuery.  It may need adjusting for templates that rearrange the configurable product template as it precisely walks up and down the DOM tree.

I placed it in my template file Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/js/components.phtml

Explanation of how it works: It hooks onto the dropdrop change event and using the setTimeout function, runs **after** all the other hooked events run to autoselect the next dropdown if there's only one option.  This can then cascade if the dropdown after that also only has one option.

```
<script>
/* Andrew Davie 100118 
Where there is only one option left in the dropdowns, autoselect it.
*/
require(['jquery'], function($){ 
    $('select[id^="attribute"]').change(function(){
        var picked = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
                autoselect(picked);  //do the autoselect after everything else.
        }, 0);

    });
    function autoselect(picked){
        var nextsel = $(picked).parent().parent().next().find('select[id^="attribute"]');
        if($(nextsel).children().length==2){
            $(nextsel).find(':nth-child(2)', picked).prop('selected',true);
            $(nextsel).change();
        };
    };
});
</script>
<?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
```